# Django Rest Framework custom message for 404 errors

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a generic class based view:

```
class ProjectDetails(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    # Rest of definition
```

And in my `urls.py`, I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProjectDetails.as_view())
]
```

When the API is called with a non-existent id, it returns `HTTP 404` response with the content:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Is it possible to modify this response?

I need to customize error message **for this view only**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This solution affect all views:**

Surely you can supply your custom exception handler: [Custom exception handling](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework import status

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND:
        response.data['custom_field'] = 'some_custom_value'

    return response
```

Sure you can skip default `rest_framework.views.exception_handler` and make it completely raw.

Note: remember to mention your handler in `django.conf.settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['EXCEPTION_HANDLER']`

**Solution for specific view:**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
# rest of the imports

class ProjectDetails(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()

    def handle_exception(self, exc):
        if isinstance(exc, Http404):
            return Response({'data': 'your custom response'}, 
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return super(ProjectDetails, self).handle_exception(exc)
```

Comment: If I add this, the response will be the same for all views, right? I need it for a single view.

Comment: @Arun for all view, yeah. I haven't noticed that you need it to be for specific view.

Comment: @Arun i've updated my question with your specific case.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible by overriding specific methods like `update`, `retrieve` as:

```
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.response import Response


class ProjectDetails(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return Response(data={"cusom": "message"})

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return Response(data={"cusom": "message"})
```

Comment: This answer doesn't handle `PUT` and `PATCH` methods.:)

Comment: @vishes_shell Yeah, but now it does :)